# when new column added in user table spring login fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, hibernate

After updating  user entity parent class spring login fails.

removing new column from class works fine.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Parent {

    @Column()
    private String id;

    //added new column
    @Column()
    private Date created;

}
```

```
@Entity()
@Table("users")
public class User extends Parent {

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

hql query or query method

```
/*hql query return user = null*/
@Query(value = "select u from user u where u.username = ?1")
public User findByUsername(String username);
```

native sql

```
/*native sql query throws exception java.sql.SQLException: Column 'clazz_' not found.*/
@Query(value = "select * from user u where u.username = ?1",nativeQuery =true)
public User findByUsername(String username);
```

Comment: did you check if your users table  has the new columns in the dataBase

Comment: @Hamza database also updated
and column also present in ddl script

Comment: some how @param works. 
    ```@Query(value="select u from User u where u.username = :username")
    public User findByUsername(@Param ("username") String username);```